# Incorrect renders in Eevee and Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I'm having a weird issue I've never seen before. My model is rendering fine in Render Preview mode with Cycles selected, but when I actually do a Render Image, I get garbage. The orange dome, the nacelle behind it, and my lights inside the dome are all gone, and the render lacks color. First image here is the preview (correct), second image is the render (garbage). Same result in Eevee. I can't figure out for the life of me what I'm doing wrong.

Blender 3.3.1 LTS, Mac Studio (M1 Ultra, 64GB RAM), MacOS Ventura 13.0.1.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hello asalaw! Could it be, that you disabled the render visibility for some collections or single objects?

Comment: Thanks for answering! You're close--I discovered one of the collections was corrupted (it had a red icon that I did not set). I took all the objects out of it and deleted the collection, and that fixed the problem. Thanks again!